# How would I create a keyboard shortcut that runs an async function in python?

Tags: python, discord

Currently making a Discord bot, and the function to send messages has to be "await"ed, and i wanted to bind it to a keyboard shortcut, how would i go about doing that.

Comment: With the amount of details you put into your question you won't get an answer since noone knows what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the way you would expect it, bc the discord api is not able to view your keystrokes.

However, you can make a Discord api even trigger when another "software" detects your keystroke. however the script would have to run in the background whenever you want to use the shortcut.

I suggest using **Pynput** to detect / simulate keystrokes.